# How to define dependency between tests in MStest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, automation, selenium, mstest

I have some tests which are dependent on the success and failure of some tests. How can I define dependency as I am using VS2010 Mstest and selenium. 
E.g

if test1 is failed then dont run test5, test 6. is this possible.

Comment: I like that MbUnit/Gallio allows me to write a test that depends on another test. I also like that I can write Assert.IsGreaterThan(1, 2) instead of just IsTrue(1 > 2). It just feels better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit Tests should always be isolated and completly non dependent on and thing else to run, not make non-fragile.

You could setup catagories with MSTest to seperate them into deferent logical structures.

A great book to find more details is this [http://artofunittesting.com](http://artofunittesting.com/)

Roy has also does alot of public speaking which is recorded online

Cheers

Comment: I have a processor running at the background which usually checks for after every 3 minutes...and after registration of form it then change the status. I have to first check if status = abc then run 3,4,5 tests otherwise dont.

Comment: @Sam - What is is that you want to assert in your tests? That the processor is working correctly? If so, then your test should (1) create test data; (2) initialise processor; (3) invoke the processor code synchronously on the test data; (4) assert that the data has the correct state. If your tests require registered forms, and the processor bit is merely to get the forms into the correct state for the test to begin, then you can (1) create a mock form that is in the correct state - and eliminate the dependency on the processor altogether; (2) perform the function; (3) assert success/failure.

Answer (score 1):

**Tests shouldn't have dependencies between them.**

If you have dependencies, then running them in a different order, or in isolation will cause them to fail sporadically - this can be very confusing for anyone else that is running the tests.

It's much better to define tests that setup their own data and assert something specific. You can use a mocking framework like [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) to reduce the dependencies between modules of code by faking (mocking) areas that aren't relevant to your test. This is made much easier if you also use a [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) framework like [Microsoft Unity](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2D24F179-E0A6-49D7-89C4-5B67D939F91B) as your code will have many more seams where mocking can be applied.

Comment: A VS unit testing infrastructure can be used to create automated integration testing. It would be nice to be able to define dependencies between tests as method attributes and let VS to figure out the right order of execution.
Creating ordered tests is like creating ordered builds in C++. They require additional maintenance and it is very easy to break them.

Comment: @Dennis - tests should be readable, maintainable, and trustworthy. Readable means that they are well-named, and simple enough to take in at a glance. Maintainable means that changing a bit of code doesn't cause big repercussions in the test library. Trustworthy means that it fails for one reason only - it never fails for other reasons. Tests with dependencies between them fail on all counts. Hard to read as you must understand all of the other tests; hard to maintain as changes to one test could have repercussions down stream; cannot be trusted as they could fail if an earlier test has failed.

Comment: I agree with you. It is all good and fine for unit-testing but is not related to this question. That's why I put a negative feedback on your response. Neither author of the original post, nor me are talking about pure unit-tests here.

Comment: @Dennis - Awesome. I like people who agree with me. :-) But I wasn't just talking about pure unit tests either. I think that the principal holds for all kinds of testing. If you avoid dependencies between your tests, they will be easier to read, easier to maintain, and more trustworthy than if you have dependencies. I think my advice to the OP was right on. He asked a question that indicated he was on the wrong track, and my response was intended to help him get back on to the right track. But thanks for the comments - anonymous negative feedback can be frustrating.

Comment: It is correct for unit-tests but is not related to integration tests Unit tests should test isolated functionality. We say that tests have dependencies if they execute the same piece of code. As a result, if a common code is broken it will break a number of tests instead of one test. It is usually an indication that functionality under test is not properly decoupled or unit-test does not do a proper isolation using mocks.

Comment: Integration tests run the big part of the same infrastructure for every test. They cannot be independent by definition. Let’s say you have three layers of architecture: data access, configuration, and business logic. If the data access layer is broken it will break most of the tests in the configuration and business logic layer. There is no point to execute them in such case.

Comment: It would be really useful to tell that a test in the configuration layer depends on particular tests in the data access layers. If the data access layer test fail it should not execute dependant tests because it will be a waste of machine time (integration tests are slow), they will fail anyway. It will also simplify the diagnostic. You will be able to see what tests are really broken because of the bug without scrolling hundred pages with a list of all affected tests.

Comment: @Dennis - Aha, I take your point. I hadn't been thinking about it from the perspective of integration tests that needn't be run if tests lower in the stack are failing. That makes a lot of sense. What you state refers to a "logical" dependency. I had assumed (perhaps mistakenly) that the OP referred to a "stateful" dependency - test1 finishes successfully and leaves the database in the correct state for test2 to begin, but if test1 failed, then the database will be in a weird state so test2 will fail... Stateful dependencies lead to awful test code - unreadable, untrustworthy, unmaintainable.